# How to retrieve the current app folder where my android app has access?

Tags: android, android-camera, mediastore, android-mediarecorder

I am starting a cam intent in my app and want that the picture will be stored inside my app folder in a images folder. To achieve this I am starting the cam intent like this

```
public void startCamAction(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, this.getApplicationContext().getDir("images", MODE_PRIVATE));
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), TAKE_PICTURE);
}
```

In the next Activity I want to do something with this picuture but I guess its not working because my app has no access to this folder. The folder where the picture has been stored is

```
content:://media/external/images/media/20
```

This is not the desired path, how do I have to configure it so that the picture will be stored inside my app folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `content:://media/external/images/media/20` is a `Uri` **not a real file path**..

So If you want to get real path from this Uri then you have to do something like,

```
Uri uri = content:://media/external/images/media/20
String imageFile = getRealPathFromURI(uri);
```

and the method `getRealPathFromURI()` is

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
               .query(contentURI, null, null, null, null); 
    cursor.moveToFirst(); 
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
    return cursor.getString(idx); 
}
```

**Update:**

Also from your code line,

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, this.getApplicationContext().getDir("images", MODE_PRIVATE));
```

Your captured images are stored in your **application's internal storage**. So you can access this directory within your application in any activity.

To retrieve a files from this directory you can use the simple file operation.

Like,

```
File directory = this.getApplicationContext().getDir("images", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Thanks for your post! I am wondering why the picture has been stored on the external storage? I did not configured this in the creation of the intent. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Actually, by default Android Camera stored the captured image in `/DCIM` directory. And also sometime  `intent.putExtra` is not working on some android devices. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Context.getExternalCacheDir()
Context.getExternalFilesDir(String type)
```

You will get the directory on the SD card where your app has access. It will look something like

```
/sdcard/Android/your.app.package.name/
```

And don't forget to add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Not really answering the question. The picture is already saved in the external direction (See the Content URI). He wants to save the picture in the app data directory.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the camera can save to the directory of an app. Mainly because of rights issues.

Best is to store it to external store (as you have done, judging from the URI: `content://media/external/images/media/20` )

You can always copy the file using this URI and save it in your app data directory, and then remove it from the external directory.

Other solution is to specify a own ContentProvider. In this ContentProvider you can save the file.
http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.be/2012/04/save-captured-image-to-applications.html